# jQuery scrollbar plugin in absolute div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I want to use the jquery scrollbar plugin, but it won't work.
I have an example for you below.
Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.scrollbar-outer').scrollbar();
});
```

```css
/*************** SCROLLBAR BASE CSS ***************/
 
.scroll-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
}
 
.scroll-wrapper > .scroll-content {
    border: none !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: none;
    max-width: none !important;
    overflow: scroll !important;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0;
    width: auto !important;
}
 
.scroll-wrapper > .scroll-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
 
.scroll-element {
    display: none;
}
.scroll-element, .scroll-element div {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
 
.scroll-element.scroll-x.scroll-scrollx_visible,
.scroll-element.scroll-y.scroll-scrolly_visible {
    display: block;
}
 
.scroll-element .scroll-bar,
.scroll-element .scroll-arrow {
    cursor: default;
}
 
.scroll-textarea {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-top-color: #999999;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content > textarea {
    border: none !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: none !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    overflow: scroll !important;
    outline: none;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content > textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
 
 
 
 
/*************** SIMPLE OUTER SCROLLBAR ***************/
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element,
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element div
{
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 12px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y {
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 12px;
}
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x .scroll-element_outer { height: 8px; top: 2px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y .scroll-element_outer { left: 2px; width: 8px; }
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-element_outer { overflow: hidden; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-element_track { background-color: #eeeeee; }
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-element_outer,
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-element_track,
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-bar {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-bar { background-color: #d9d9d9; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-bar:hover { background-color: #c2c2c2; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-draggable .scroll-bar { background-color: #919191; }
 
 
/* scrollbar height/width & offset from container borders */
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-content.scroll-scrolly_visible { left: -12px; margin-left: 12px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-content.scroll-scrollx_visible { top:  -12px; margin-top:  12px; }
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x .scroll-bar { min-width: 10px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y .scroll-bar { min-height: 10px; }
 
 
/* update scrollbar offset if both scrolls are visible */
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x.scroll-scrolly_visible .scroll-element_track { left: -14px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y.scroll-scrollx_visible .scroll-element_track { top: -14px; }
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x.scroll-scrolly_visible .scroll-element_size { left: -14px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y.scroll-scrollx_visible .scroll-element_size { top: -14px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.js"></script>

<body>
 <div style="position:absolute;background-color:red;top:30px;left:30px;right:30px;bottom:30px;font-size:50px">
  <div style="position:relative;height:100%;width:100%;">
   <div class="scrollbar-outer" style="max-height:100%;overflow:auto;">
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

So I have this div which is absolute positioned, how can I make the content inside scrollable with this plugin? It seems to me the 100% height for the content does not work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Obviously I don't  want a fixed height. The height and width of my outer div should always have the maximum size with a 'border' of 25px to the boundary.

Comment: Where is the `.scroll-wraper`in the HTML?

Comment: The scroll-wrapper is made by the plugin, none of my business i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsFiddle provided by Author of the scrollbarplugin:

https://jsfiddle.net/tuzofkw1/

It was a problem connected to the CSS file.
Thanks a lot to Yuriy Khabarov!

So the solution looks like this:

```js
!function(l,e){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],e):e(l.jQuery)}(this,function(l){"use strict";function e(e){if(t.webkit&&!e)return{height:0,width:0};if(!t.data.outer){var o={border:"none","box-sizing":"content-box",height:"200px",margin:"0",padding:"0",width:"200px"};t.data.inner=l("<div>").css(l.extend({},o)),t.data.outer=l("<div>").css(l.extend({left:"-1000px",overflow:"scroll",position:"absolute",top:"-1000px"},o)).append(t.data.inner).appendTo("body")}return t.data.outer.scrollLeft(1e3).scrollTop(1e3),{height:Math.ceil(t.data.outer.offset().top-t.data.inner.offset().top||0),width:Math.ceil(t.data.outer.offset().left-t.data.inner.offset().left||0)}}function o(){var l=e(!0);return!(l.height||l.width)}function s(l){var e=l.originalEvent;return e.axis&&e.axis===e.HORIZONTAL_AXIS?!1:e.wheelDeltaX?!1:!0}var r=!1,t={data:{index:0,name:"scrollbar"},macosx:/mac/i.test(navigator.platform),mobile:/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent),overlay:null,scroll:null,scrolls:[],webkit:/webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&!/edge\/\d+/i.test(navigator.userAgent)};t.scrolls.add=function(l){this.remove(l).push(l)},t.scrolls.remove=function(e){for(;l.inArray(e,this)>=0;)this.splice(l.inArray(e,this),1);return this};var i={autoScrollSize:!0,autoUpdate:!0,debug:!1,disableBodyScroll:!1,duration:200,ignoreMobile:!1,ignoreOverlay:!1,scrollStep:30,showArrows:!1,stepScrolling:!0,scrollx:null,scrolly:null,onDestroy:null,onInit:null,onScroll:null,onUpdate:null},n=function(s){t.scroll||(t.overlay=o(),t.scroll=e(),a(),l(window).resize(function(){var l=!1;if(t.scroll&&(t.scroll.height||t.scroll.width)){var o=e();(o.height!==t.scroll.height||o.width!==t.scroll.width)&&(t.scroll=o,l=!0)}a(l)})),this.container=s,this.namespace=".scrollbar_"+t.data.index++,this.options=l.extend({},i,window.jQueryScrollbarOptions||{}),this.scrollTo=null,this.scrollx={},this.scrolly={},s.data(t.data.name,this),t.scrolls.add(this)};n.prototype={destroy:function(){if(this.wrapper){this.container.removeData(t.data.name),t.scrolls.remove(this);var e=this.container.scrollLeft(),o=this.container.scrollTop();this.container.insertBefore(this.wrapper).css({height:"",margin:"","max-height":""}).removeClass("scroll-content scroll-scrollx_visible scroll-scrolly_visible").off(this.namespace).scrollLeft(e).scrollTop(o),this.scrollx.scroll.removeClass("scroll-scrollx_visible").find("div").andSelf().off(this.namespace),this.scrolly.scroll.removeClass("scroll-scrolly_visible").find("div").andSelf().off(this.namespace),this.wrapper.remove(),l(document).add("body").off(this.namespace),l.isFunction(this.options.onDestroy)&&this.options.onDestroy.apply(this,[this.container])}},init:function(e){var o=this,r=this.container,i=this.containerWrapper||r,n=this.namespace,c=l.extend(this.options,e||{}),a={x:this.scrollx,y:this.scrolly},d=this.wrapper,h={scrollLeft:r.scrollLeft(),scrollTop:r.scrollTop()};if(t.mobile&&c.ignoreMobile||t.overlay&&c.ignoreOverlay||t.macosx&&!t.webkit)return!1;if(d)i.css({height:"auto","margin-bottom":-1*t.scroll.height+"px","margin-right":-1*t.scroll.width+"px","max-height":""});else{if(this.wrapper=d=l("<div>").addClass("scroll-wrapper").addClass(r.attr("class")).css("position","absolute"==r.css("position")?"absolute":"relative").insertBefore(r).append(r),r.is("textarea")&&(this.containerWrapper=i=l("<div>").insertBefore(r).append(r),d.addClass("scroll-textarea")),i.addClass("scroll-content").css({height:"auto","margin-bottom":-1*t.scroll.height+"px","margin-right":-1*t.scroll.width+"px","max-height":""}),r.on("scroll"+n,function(e){l.isFunction(c.onScroll)&&c.onScroll.call(o,{maxScroll:a.y.maxScrollOffset,scroll:r.scrollTop(),size:a.y.size,visible:a.y.visible},{maxScroll:a.x.maxScrollOffset,scroll:r.scrollLeft(),size:a.x.size,visible:a.x.visible}),a.x.isVisible&&a.x.scroll.bar.css("left",r.scrollLeft()*a.x.kx+"px"),a.y.isVisible&&a.y.scroll.bar.css("top",r.scrollTop()*a.y.kx+"px")}),d.on("scroll"+n,function(){d.scrollTop(0).scrollLeft(0)}),c.disableBodyScroll){var p=function(l){s(l)?a.y.isVisible&&a.y.mousewheel(l):a.x.isVisible&&a.x.mousewheel(l)};d.on("MozMousePixelScroll"+n,p),d.on("mousewheel"+n,p),t.mobile&&d.on("touchstart"+n,function(e){var o=e.originalEvent.touches&&e.originalEvent.touches[0]||e,s={pageX:o.pageX,pageY:o.pageY},t={left:r.scrollLeft(),top:r.scrollTop()};l(document).on("touchmove"+n,function(l){var e=l.originalEvent.targetTouches&&l.originalEvent.targetTouches[0]||l;r.scrollLeft(t.left+s.pageX-e.pageX),r.scrollTop(t.top+s.pageY-e.pageY),l.preventDefault()}),l(document).on("touchend"+n,function(){l(document).off(n)})})}l.isFunction(c.onInit)&&c.onInit.apply(this,[r])}l.each(a,function(e,t){var i=null,d=1,h="x"===e?"scrollLeft":"scrollTop",p=c.scrollStep,u=function(){var l=r[h]();r[h](l+p),1==d&&l+p>=f&&(l=r[h]()),-1==d&&f>=l+p&&(l=r[h]()),r[h]()==l&&i&&i()},f=0;t.scroll||(t.scroll=o._getScroll(c["scroll"+e]).addClass("scroll-"+e),c.showArrows&&t.scroll.addClass("scroll-element_arrows_visible"),t.mousewheel=function(l){if(!t.isVisible||"x"===e&&s(l))return!0;if("y"===e&&!s(l))return a.x.mousewheel(l),!0;var i=-1*l.originalEvent.wheelDelta||l.originalEvent.detail,n=t.size-t.visible-t.offset;return(i>0&&n>f||0>i&&f>0)&&(f+=i,0>f&&(f=0),f>n&&(f=n),o.scrollTo=o.scrollTo||{},o.scrollTo[h]=f,setTimeout(function(){o.scrollTo&&(r.stop().animate(o.scrollTo,240,"linear",function(){f=r[h]()}),o.scrollTo=null)},1)),l.preventDefault(),!1},t.scroll.on("MozMousePixelScroll"+n,t.mousewheel).on("mousewheel"+n,t.mousewheel).on("mouseenter"+n,function(){f=r[h]()}),t.scroll.find(".scroll-arrow, .scroll-element_track").on("mousedown"+n,function(s){if(1!=s.which)return!0;d=1;var n={eventOffset:s["x"===e?"pageX":"pageY"],maxScrollValue:t.size-t.visible-t.offset,scrollbarOffset:t.scroll.bar.offset()["x"===e?"left":"top"],scrollbarSize:t.scroll.bar["x"===e?"outerWidth":"outerHeight"]()},a=0,v=0;return l(this).hasClass("scroll-arrow")?(d=l(this).hasClass("scroll-arrow_more")?1:-1,p=c.scrollStep*d,f=d>0?n.maxScrollValue:0):(d=n.eventOffset>n.scrollbarOffset+n.scrollbarSize?1:n.eventOffset<n.scrollbarOffset?-1:0,p=Math.round(.75*t.visible)*d,f=n.eventOffset-n.scrollbarOffset-(c.stepScrolling?1==d?n.scrollbarSize:0:Math.round(n.scrollbarSize/2)),f=r[h]()+f/t.kx),o.scrollTo=o.scrollTo||{},o.scrollTo[h]=c.stepScrolling?r[h]()+p:f,c.stepScrolling&&(i=function(){f=r[h](),clearInterval(v),clearTimeout(a),a=0,v=0},a=setTimeout(function(){v=setInterval(u,40)},c.duration+100)),setTimeout(function(){o.scrollTo&&(r.animate(o.scrollTo,c.duration),o.scrollTo=null)},1),o._handleMouseDown(i,s)}),t.scroll.bar.on("mousedown"+n,function(s){if(1!=s.which)return!0;var i=s["x"===e?"pageX":"pageY"],c=r[h]();return t.scroll.addClass("scroll-draggable"),l(document).on("mousemove"+n,function(l){var o=parseInt((l["x"===e?"pageX":"pageY"]-i)/t.kx,10);r[h](c+o)}),o._handleMouseDown(function(){t.scroll.removeClass("scroll-draggable"),f=r[h]()},s)}))}),l.each(a,function(l,e){var o="scroll-scroll"+l+"_visible",s="x"==l?a.y:a.x;e.scroll.removeClass(o),s.scroll.removeClass(o),i.removeClass(o)}),l.each(a,function(e,o){l.extend(o,"x"==e?{offset:parseInt(r.css("left"),10)||0,size:r.prop("scrollWidth"),visible:d.width()}:{offset:parseInt(r.css("top"),10)||0,size:r.prop("scrollHeight"),visible:d.height()})}),this._updateScroll("x",this.scrollx),this._updateScroll("y",this.scrolly),l.isFunction(c.onUpdate)&&c.onUpdate.apply(this,[r]),l.each(a,function(l,e){var o="x"===l?"left":"top",s="x"===l?"outerWidth":"outerHeight",t="x"===l?"width":"height",i=parseInt(r.css(o),10)||0,n=e.size,a=e.visible+i,d=e.scroll.size[s]()+(parseInt(e.scroll.size.css(o),10)||0);c.autoScrollSize&&(e.scrollbarSize=parseInt(d*a/n,10),e.scroll.bar.css(t,e.scrollbarSize+"px")),e.scrollbarSize=e.scroll.bar[s](),e.kx=(d-e.scrollbarSize)/(n-a)||1,e.maxScrollOffset=n-a}),r.scrollLeft(h.scrollLeft).scrollTop(h.scrollTop).trigger("scroll")},_getScroll:function(e){var o={advanced:['<div class="scroll-element">','<div class="scroll-element_corner"></div>','<div class="scroll-arrow scroll-arrow_less"></div>','<div class="scroll-arrow scroll-arrow_more"></div>','<div class="scroll-element_outer">','<div class="scroll-element_size"></div>','<div class="scroll-element_inner-wrapper">','<div class="scroll-element_inner scroll-element_track">','<div class="scroll-element_inner-bottom"></div>',"</div>","</div>",'<div class="scroll-bar">','<div class="scroll-bar_body">','<div class="scroll-bar_body-inner"></div>',"</div>",'<div class="scroll-bar_bottom"></div>','<div class="scroll-bar_center"></div>',"</div>","</div>","</div>"].join(""),simple:['<div class="scroll-element">','<div class="scroll-element_outer">','<div class="scroll-element_size"></div>','<div class="scroll-element_track"></div>','<div class="scroll-bar"></div>',"</div>","</div>"].join("")};return o[e]&&(e=o[e]),e||(e=o.simple),e="string"==typeof e?l(e).appendTo(this.wrapper):l(e),l.extend(e,{bar:e.find(".scroll-bar"),size:e.find(".scroll-element_size"),track:e.find(".scroll-element_track")}),e},_handleMouseDown:function(e,o){var s=this.namespace;return l(document).on("blur"+s,function(){l(document).add("body").off(s),e&&e()}),l(document).on("dragstart"+s,function(l){return l.preventDefault(),!1}),l(document).on("mouseup"+s,function(){l(document).add("body").off(s),e&&e()}),l("body").on("selectstart"+s,function(l){return l.preventDefault(),!1}),o&&o.preventDefault(),!1},_updateScroll:function(e,o){var s=this.container,r=this.containerWrapper||s,i="scroll-scroll"+e+"_visible",n="x"===e?this.scrolly:this.scrollx,c=parseInt(this.container.css("x"===e?"left":"top"),10)||0,a=this.wrapper,d=o.size,h=o.visible+c;o.isVisible=d-h>1,o.isVisible?(o.scroll.addClass(i),n.scroll.addClass(i),r.addClass(i)):(o.scroll.removeClass(i),n.scroll.removeClass(i),r.removeClass(i)),"y"===e&&(s.is("textarea")||h>d?r.css({height:h+t.scroll.height+"px","max-height":"none"}):r.css({"max-height":h+t.scroll.height+"px"})),(o.size!=s.prop("scrollWidth")||n.size!=s.prop("scrollHeight")||o.visible!=a.width()||n.visible!=a.height()||o.offset!=(parseInt(s.css("left"),10)||0)||n.offset!=(parseInt(s.css("top"),10)||0))&&(l.extend(this.scrollx,{offset:parseInt(s.css("left"),10)||0,size:s.prop("scrollWidth"),visible:a.width()}),l.extend(this.scrolly,{offset:parseInt(s.css("top"),10)||0,size:this.container.prop("scrollHeight"),visible:a.height()}),this._updateScroll("x"===e?"y":"x",n))}};var c=n;l.fn.scrollbar=function(e,o){return"string"!=typeof e&&(o=e,e="init"),"undefined"==typeof o&&(o=[]),l.isArray(o)||(o=[o]),this.not("body, .scroll-wrapper").each(function(){var s=l(this),r=s.data(t.data.name);(r||"init"===e)&&(r||(r=new c(s)),r[e]&&r[e].apply(r,o))}),this},l.fn.scrollbar.options=i;var a=function(){var l=0,e=0;return function(o){var s,i,n,c,d,h,p;for(s=0;s<t.scrolls.length;s++)c=t.scrolls[s],i=c.container,n=c.options,d=c.wrapper,h=c.scrollx,p=c.scrolly,(o||n.autoUpdate&&d&&d.is(":visible")&&(i.prop("scrollWidth")!=h.size||i.prop("scrollHeight")!=p.size||d.width()!=h.visible||d.height()!=p.visible))&&(c.init(),n.debug&&(window.console&&console.log({scrollHeight:i.prop("scrollHeight")+":"+c.scrolly.size,scrollWidth:i.prop("scrollWidth")+":"+c.scrollx.size,visibleHeight:d.height()+":"+c.scrolly.visible,visibleWidth:d.width()+":"+c.scrollx.visible},!0),e++));r&&e>10?(window.console&&console.log("Scroll updates exceed 10"),a=function(){}):(clearTimeout(l),l=setTimeout(a,300))}}();window.angular&&!function(l){l.module("jQueryScrollbar",[]).provider("jQueryScrollbar",function(){var e=i;return{setOptions:function(o){l.extend(e,o)},$get:function(){return{options:l.copy(e)}}}}).directive("jqueryScrollbar",["jQueryScrollbar","$parse",function(l,e){return{restrict:"AC",link:function(o,s,r){var t=e(r.jqueryScrollbar),i=t(o);s.scrollbar(i||l.options).on("$destroy",function(){s.scrollbar("destroy")})}}}])}(window.angular)});
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.scrollbar-outer').scrollbar();
});
```

```css
/*************** SCROLLBAR BASE CSS ***************/
 
.scroll-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
}
 
.scroll-wrapper > .scroll-content {
    border: none !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: none;
    max-width: none !important;
    overflow: scroll !important;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0;
    width: auto !important;
}
 
.scroll-wrapper > .scroll-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
 
.scroll-element {
    display: none;
}
.scroll-element, .scroll-element div {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
 
.scroll-element.scroll-x.scroll-scrollx_visible,
.scroll-element.scroll-y.scroll-scrolly_visible {
    display: block;
}
 
.scroll-element .scroll-bar,
.scroll-element .scroll-arrow {
    cursor: default;
}
 
.scroll-textarea {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-top-color: #999999;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content > textarea {
    border: none !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: none !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    overflow: scroll !important;
    outline: none;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content > textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
 
 
 
 
/*************** SIMPLE OUTER SCROLLBAR ***************/
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element,
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element div
{
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 12px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y {
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 12px;
}
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x .scroll-element_outer { height: 8px; top: 2px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y .scroll-element_outer { left: 2px; width: 8px; }
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-element_outer { overflow: hidden; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-element_track { background-color: #eeeeee; }
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-element_outer,
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-element_track,
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-bar {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-bar { background-color: #d9d9d9; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element .scroll-bar:hover { background-color: #c2c2c2; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-draggable .scroll-bar { background-color: #919191; }
 
 
/* scrollbar height/width & offset from container borders */
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-content.scroll-scrolly_visible { left: -12px; margin-left: 12px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-content.scroll-scrollx_visible { top:  -12px; margin-top:  12px; }
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x .scroll-bar { min-width: 10px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y .scroll-bar { min-height: 10px; }
 
 
/* update scrollbar offset if both scrolls are visible */
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x.scroll-scrolly_visible .scroll-element_track { left: -14px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y.scroll-scrollx_visible .scroll-element_track { top: -14px; }
 
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-x.scroll-scrolly_visible .scroll-element_size { left: -14px; }
.scrollbar-outer > .scroll-element.scroll-y.scroll-scrollx_visible .scroll-element_size { top: -14px; }






.scrollbar-outer {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:absolute;background-color:red;top:30px;left:30px;right:30px;bottom:30px;font-size:50px">
  <div style="position:relative;height:100%;width:100%;">
   <div class="scrollbar-outer">
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
    test<br>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```