# horizontal scrollbars and disable vertical scroll

Tags: css

How to add horizontal scrollbars?

(Have disabled the cutom scrollbars to begin with)

http://jsfiddle.net/s5ng001z/13/

## html

```
<div style="height:70px; width:200px">
  <div class="scrollbar_content scrollbar-inner">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## css

```
.scrollbar_content {
    height:100%;
  width:100%;
  min-width:100%;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.box {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:2px;
  background:red;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
```

Comment: This is the CSS to a plugin called jQuery CSS Customizable Scrollbar. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150350/jquery-scrollbar-plugin-in-absolute-div

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this style `white-space: nowrap;` to `.scrollbar_content`
http://jsfiddle.net/s5ng001z/14/

```
.scrollbar_content {
    height:100%;
  width:100%;
  min-width:100%;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;        // add this
}

.box {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:2px;
  background:red;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
```